# App crashing using MMDrawerController Gesture in drawer

Tags: ios, swift, slidingdrawer, drawer, mmdrawercontroller

I am using `MMDrawerController` for showing drawer. My app is crashing on clicking on the drawer menu options. It works well in iOS9 but crashes in iOS8. Does anyone have any idea about what is happening here. Am I missing something here?

I am getting the below error when i click on the left menu bar option:

> [UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer view]: message sent to deallocated
>   instance 0x155e6d9a0

Comment: I used `MMDrawerController` in an old App. Immediately changed to `SWRevealViewController` which is way better and stable.

Comment: And I think this means that your MMDrawerVC was deallocated at some point. When you tap left menu button on your frontVC it crashes. Better find out where does this happen

Comment: You can open a new issue on its [Github Repository](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController/issues)